# java hsperfdata directory

Tags: java, directory

Java creates `hsperfdata` directory usually in the `/tmp` directory. What purpose does this directory serve? What is the effect on the JVM if this directory is accidentally deleted?

Answer (score 50):

That directory is part of a Java performance counter. There's a JVM argument for turning it off: see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76327/how-can-i-prevent-java-from-creating-hsperfdata-files) on StackOverflow.