# Cannot move /tmp/hsperfdata_hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

My hadoop is running perfectly well , I am using hadoop-0.20.2.

But problem is I am not able to move /tmp/hsperfdata_hadoop file , so after a while /tmp gets filled with data and my process get time out or killed.
I have to move this folder , please help me with its configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of links you may find interesting to read:

- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6447182
- [java hsperfdata directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655188/java-hsperfdata-directory)
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6284

From looking through those pages, this is a java thing (storage of performance counters), which may or may not be easily configurable for another location. Is your /tmp directory full or relativey small?

Can you run a `df -h` from your command line, and see how much space is assigned to that partition, and dig into /tmp to discover what else might be consuming the space.

I'm surprised that your OS and other application are not adversely affected by the lack of temporary storage space.

Comment: Thank you , your links are very helpful.Still I didnt get anything to change its path , If you get anything please let me know.I dont wana disable hsprefdata.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding _Djava.io.tmpdir= to your java options.

I found this in the error log output of my mapreduce job when it failed due to this directory running out of space.