# How does jconsole discover the JMX enabled processes on local system?

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

When I run `jconsole` it shows me a list of Java processes:

[image]

I could then connect to one of these and see its `MBeans`. How does it discover the JMX processes? How can I do this in a program?

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://www.cordinc.com/blog/2010/02/jmx-jconsolelike-connection-di.html) shows how to do it using [Attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html) from JDK tools.jar

Answer (score 1):

Replying since I had this question too and got an answer.
There is a JPS program in JDK which shows java processes.
I am not 100% sure (don't want to dive deep into jconsole code) but 99% sure jconsole uses the same mechanism as jps:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/tools/jps/Jps.java?av=f

```
HostIdentifier hostId = arguments.hostId();
MonitoredHost monitoredHost = MonitoredHost.getMonitoredHost(hostId);
// get the set active JVMs on the specified host.
Set<Integer> jvms = monitoredHost.activeVms();
```

These class are part of tools.jar, you need to include it in the project's classpath.

If we go deeper (I do not expose all the intermediate steps) - finally we'll know that active VMs list is populated from hsperfdata files in temporary directories:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/jvmstat/perfdata/monitor/protocol/local/PerfDataFile.java

Here is a link to know more:
[java hsperfdata directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655188/java-hsperfdata-directory)

At last, here is a code snippet allowing you to get the java processes ids:

```
sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredHost host = sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredHost.getMonitoredHost(new sun.jvmstat.monitor.HostIdentifier((String) null));
System.out.println(host.activeVms());
```

P.S.

Then you can use Attach API (as kostya mentioned) to discover the rest of needed things.