# Permission denied when using mvn cobertura plugin

Tags: maven, permissions, cobertura

I'm using maven to build my project and cobertura for UT code coverage collection.
My problem is when I try to build the project, I met the error below, finally I found the failure is caused by cobertura plugin when I was issuing the command : `mvn cobertura:instrument`.

```
[INFO] Unable to obtain CommandsFile location.
Embedded error: Permission denied
```

I tried to go through the directories and I think I have the permission. 
Have anyone ever seen the failure before? How to debug it?

```
$ mvn cobertura:instrument
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order: 
[INFO]   MyProject
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building XXXXXX
[INFO]    task-segment: [cobertura:instrument]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [cobertura:instrument]
[INFO] Skipping cobertura mojo for project with packaging type 'pom'
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ato-client
[INFO]    task-segment: [cobertura:instrument]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [cobertura:instrument]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to obtain CommandsFile location.

Embedded error: Permission denied
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Unable to obtain CommandsFile location.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:703)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:553)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:523)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:371)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:332)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to obtain CommandsFile location.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura.tasks.AbstractTask.executeJava(AbstractTask.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura.tasks.InstrumentTask.execute(InstrumentTask.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura.CoberturaInstrumentMojo.execute(CoberturaInstrumentMojo.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:678)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1828)
    at net.sourceforge.cobertura.util.CommandLineBuilder.<init>(CommandLineBuilder.java:96)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura.tasks.CommandLineArguments.getCommandsFile(CommandLineArguments.java:82)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura.tasks.AbstractTask.executeJava(AbstractTask.java:191)
    ... 20 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 22 09:30:25 CST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/241M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your current user doesn't have write permissions to the temporary folder (check `java.io.tmpdir` system property value):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied 
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) 
at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704) 
at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792) 
at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1828) 
at net.sourceforge.cobertura.util.CommandLineBuilder.(CommandLineBuilder.java:96) 
at enter code here
```

Comment: I built the project in my user home directory, so I think I have the permission

Comment: ll /tmp/ please 。copy result !

Comment: yep, I found someone changed the owner of /tmp and chmod to 744.

Answer (score 2):

The error said the user of java process has no write permission on temp directory (/tmp).

Java process will write pid to a file on the temp directory.

Jps/jstat can use this pid file to get jvm informations.

See also:

- [jstat](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jvmstat-142257.html)
- [How can I prevent Java from creating hsperfdata files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76327/how-can-i-prevent-java-from-creating-hsperfdata-files)
- [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html#hostidentifier)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the user has permissions to write to the standard temporary file directory provided by the java configuration?