# Ignite - hsprefdata_ignite File deletion

Tags: spring-boot, ignite, apacheignite

I am using CentOS as my Environment and running Ignite on it my CentOS create hsprefdata_ignite folder in /tmp directory.
But CentOS run a cron to delete these file in every 10 and 30th day , does it can affect my node and can be possible reason of ignite node crashing

Answer (score 0):

it's just some performance monitoring data. Disabling it should not affect Ignite robustness.

Check out this post:
[How can I prevent Java from creating hsperfdata files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76327/how-can-i-prevent-java-from-creating-hsperfdata-files)